# How to change the automatically populated file name in the browser's Save As dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, web

Requirements for a *closed system*: Firefox, client side code only, HTML, CSS and JavaScript/Jquery but no other open source libraries.

Need to save a complete web page. The built in functionality works great, except that I need to set the file name dynamically.

Currently, the built in Save as mechanism populates the file name (in the save as dialog) with the html title attribute.

However, I need the file name to be dynamically populated each time. (i.e. File1, File2, File3) - in other words I need to set the file name on each save via some code.

How do I do this leveraging the browser or writing it all myself?

Thank You!

**EDIT**

Is there an event that notices when save as is clicked and change the title right then?

Worst case, can I implement my own save as dialog?

**EDIT 2**
I see the command to save as can be called in IE document.execCommand('SaveAs',), is there an equivalent in FF? If I open the save as dialog via java script, I assume right then I would change the title?

Comment: Sounds like you need to update the title attribute with the correct value?

Comment: Not sure it's possible at all, but you can change the title before saving. +1 anyway.

Comment: I don't know much about Firefox extension development, but I think you can write an extension to change the page title or default filename before save.

Comment: @gdoron: can I just implement my own save as dialog with a prepopulated file name then?

Comment: @epascarello: yes, but how? It all has to be in one click and ready to go with a different file name each save as.....so what i need is as soon as they open the save as dialog, the title changes, can I look for that event??

Comment: I don't think you can listen to that event, but you can create a bookmarklet to change the `<title>` *and* to save the last title (number) in some cookie or local storage, so it knows what title to set next time the bookmarklet is invoked. Then it's two clicks: run the bookmarklet, and then save the page. Too bad you only want to use Firefox, and not tools such as wget...

Comment: If it is internal, build a browser extension.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this. It is not scriptable. The file dialog is part of the OS that the browser hooks into.

Comment: I agree that it's not scriptable, but I guess that by itself is not related to the Save As dialog being created by the OS, I feel. The default file name *is* set by the browser.

Comment: Yes, it makes a call to the file dialog and passes the name, but JavaScript cannot do this itself.

Comment: @Diodeus: I see the command to save as can be called in IE document.execCommand('SaveAs',), is there an equivalent in FF? If I open the save as dialog via java script, I assume right then I would change the title?

Comment: There is an HTMl5 trick used to save the contents of the Canvas element. You may be able to grab your HTML and do the same. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063002/saving-the-html-5-canvas-image-on-local-harddrive

Comment: You'll need to set the mime type as text/html. Give it a try.

Comment: There is also a Flash-based approach: http://www.bitrepository.com/downloadify-client-side-file-generation.html

Comment: @Diodeus: the version of ff required doesn't support HTML 5 and can't use flash, thanks for looking though. (+3)

Comment: Oh gosh... such amazing requirement must be possible... the only thing that is still impossible is to rise from the grave... take a look on this hacky workaround https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37859069/how-to-change-save-image-to-file-default-name

Answer (score 0):

Try using the new html5 download attribute:

```
<a href="http://..." donwload="someFilename">Click here</a>
```

If filename is sent in response header, browser will prefer that. But if not, browser will use filename specified in download attribute.

You can even make a script to automatically display the dialog:

```
//create a element
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Click here'));
a.href = 'http://some/url';
a.download = 'filename';

//Put filename in clipboard. If download filename is ignored, user can simply paste it
var aux = document.createElement('input');
aux.setAttribute('value', a.download);
document.body.appendChild(aux);
aux.select();
document.execCommand("copy");
document.body.removeChild(aux);

document.body.insertBefore(a, document.body.firstElementChild);
a.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
//Optionally you can remove the link as well (uncomment line bellow)
//document.body.removeChild(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using an Auto Increment (AI) field in the DB which you are saving the file names to would do the trick.

1. Create a field for the file names `<filename>` in your DB table.
2. Define it as `Not Null (NN)` and as `Auto Increment (AI)` - this will give each new
   record a value in this field as a running number.
3. In your PHP file, right before saving, create a new record in the DB table and then
   pull out the auto-created field `<filename>` to a variable
   `<$newname>`.
4. Save the file with PHP as you would, with `<$newname>`
   followed by the file extension.

- You mentioned this is closed system, though if you could set a local MySQL server and then this would work. (Also this might help others who don't happen to use a closed system, heh...)