# How to change save image to file default name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a canvas HTML5 tag that is created by Caman.js.

When I click right in FF and save to file the default name for the file is canvas.png. Since I create a lot of files and need to save them this is unfortunate, because I need to set the different name for each.

What I would like to accomplish is that when saving first image save to file dialog shows firstfile.png and second secondfile.png and so on. So I don't need to change the name in the save dialog window.

How to change the default name of save to file dialog in FF using HTML and JS?

Comment: Saving with phantomjs can be easier I think if you need to do it a lot.

Comment: Hi @tomaszs, you can't change the default filename but you can replace the default menu with a custom one... Check out my answer below ;-)

Comment: I have the same question, but for an external image that loads in the page.  I'm wondering if it's possible to get the file using PHP Curl, temp save to server, and then to rename the filename before rendering the page

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> How to change the default name of save to file dialog in FF using HTML and JS?

The simple answer is that we can't.

The names are generated internally in the browser and we have no API access to this from an ordinary web page, and therefor can't change this behavior.

There are several reasons for not having direct access to the default context menu, one being security.

### Extensions

One work-around though is to write a plugin/extension for the browser and provide a custom context menu *item* which you can then give the desired behavior.

Or use some existing ones like [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/save-images/) or [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/save-image-in-folder/) - these are randomly selected just meant as examples. You may be able a better fit going through the add-on collections.

### Download attribute and context menu

If you are controlling the page you want to save the images from, you could also provide a custom context menu which allows you to save images using the A-tag and the `download` attribute which allows you to set a filename.

You would need to convert the image to an Object-URL or Data-URI and set that as source for the A-tag.

Some may object to using custom context menus for various reasons, but if this is for local usage there is no good reason saying you can't, and in other cases a good UX approach can inform the user of this behavior removing any surprises.

### Context menu example using CamanJS

Added a minimalist example to pop up the menu with a link and filename. The example uses CamanJS using the `toBase64()` method.

Since CamanJS replaced the original element it is important to attach event handlers *after* canvas has replaced them as otherwise the handler will die together with the original element in the sense they are no longer available.

```js
Caman(img, function() {
  var me = this;
  
  // from inside callback as img is now a different element
  img.oncontextmenu = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();                           // prevent default action
    lnk.download = lnk.innerHTML = "Myfile.jpg";  // set file and link name
    lnk.href = me.toBase64();                     // get Data-URI from CamanJS
    menu.style.cssText =                          // show the menu
      "left:" + e.clientX + "px; top:" + e.clientY + "px; display:block";
  };
});

window.onclick = function() {menu.style.display="none"};
```

```css
#menu {
  position:fixed;
  background:#444;
  padding:4px 7px;
  box-shadow:3px 3px 3px #000;
  display:none;
  }
#menu a {color:#fff;font:14px sans-serif}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/camanjs/4.0.0/caman.full.min.js"></script>
<img id=img src="//i.imgur.com/67E6Ujdb.jpg" crossOrigin="anonymous">
<div id="menu">
  <a id="lnk"></a>
</div>
```

NOTE: may not work in Stacksnippet with Firefox (seem to be an issue with Stacksnippet). Here is a alternative **[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/9j14Lt0p/)** in that case.

Comment: I have access, it is mine website. The last paragraph seems interesting

Comment: @tomaszs Added a minimalist example for context-menu + setting the link

Comment: it was not me downvoting

Comment: @tomaszs I didn't think so, it was more for the unknown user who did. Guess it was a strategic vote since no reason was posted. Oh well.

Answer (score 8):

To change the default name when Save AS dialog is not directly possible, But there is a workaround

You can specify the file name for file to be downloaded using `Download` Attribute in `a` tag like this

```
<a href="ImageLocation" download="filename">
```

Convert you canvas [to data url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) and assign it to `href` of `a` tag

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasId');
var yourlink= document.getElementById('linkId');
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
yourlink.href=dataURL;
```

Comment: I have to disagree.. is possible

Comment: Exactly.. I disagree when You say that is NOT directly possible, ... it is , and I even would say enough directly :D

Comment: Actually I prefer Your answer to K3N's one... (yeah obviously mine is the best) then You gain an upvote ;)

Comment: Damn I missed the "contextual menu" ... I'm too old ... u`re right...btw one should not rely on the default contextual menu... i think is a bad habit to misuse it.

Answer (score 2):

It's not quite possible to change default name, but we can create an `a` tag and give it canvas data and set `download` attr to filename of choice, and show it like a menu replacing default menu...

[image: Default and right clicked states]

Code will look something like this...

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('<a id="download-canvas">Save as image</a>').appendTo('body'); // Adding the tag to body
  var link = $('#download-canvas')

  $('body').click(function(e) {
    link.hide(0) // Hide the link on clicking anywhere else
  })
  $(document).on("contextmenu", function(e) {
    link.hide(0)
    if (e.target.nodeName == "CANVAS") { // Proceed for CANVAS nodes only
      e.preventDefault(); // Dont show default menu

      link
        .attr({ //Set the attributes for link
          href: e.target.toDataURL(),
          download: 'my-file.png'
        })
        .css({ // Position the link to current mouse position
          top: e.clientY,
          left: e.clientX,
          display: 'block'
        });

    }
  });
});

///////////////////////////////////
// Just drawing something on canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas-id'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = '#0cf';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
ctx.font = '60px sans-serif';
ctx.fillText('Hi from Canvas!', 10, canvas.height / 2 - 15);
ctx.font = '26px sans-serif';
ctx.fillText('Just right click me to download ;-)', 15, canvas.height / 2 + 35);
```

```css
/* Position the tag absolute and make it look pretty */

#download-canvas {
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 7px;
  font: 14px sans-serif;
  color: #555;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas width="500" height="300" id="canvas-id">Sorry, Your browser doesn't support canvas.</canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

I successfully did it creating on the fly an `anchor` hidden tag with right attributes, appended, trigger click, and hide it, try it out, just take care about the id attribute of the canvas element:

```
var basename = 'myfile';
function downloadAs = (function () {
    var n = 1;
    return function () {
        var afake = document.createElement('a'),
            cnv = document.getElementById('canvasId'),
            img = cnv.toDataURL("image/png");
        afake.href = img;
        afake.download = basename + "" + n++;
        afake.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(afake);
        afake.click();
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            document.body.removeChild(afake);
        }, 200);
    };
})();
```

[Here](http://www.jmvc.org/canvaseditor) You can find a working example... this is an old experiment I wrote 2yago and almost abandoned :(, btw what is important now is the fourth last icon 'export image' (a tooltip should appears) click, name it and press Export, ...humm.. yes ...if You draw something with the mouse before exporting maybe is better :D

Answer (score 0):

Hello looks like its possible if server sends a file name

```html
<img src="https://s3-eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/se-odoo-stage-1/4e35c1945e3eb656548f6ff7a0d33774c1b011f9">  TRY

<br>

<img src="https://s3-eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/se-odoo-stage-1/220347c51e4b24358d2e1a85dc2574e8a15a4014"> TO SAVE


<br>

<img src="https://s3-eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/se-odoo-stage-1/e1e9ffcaa77b5a1efc742d1031325a6cfe6efccf"> THIS IMAGES
```

if you try to save this image it autosaves as google

now if you go to network tool and https://s3-eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/se-odoo-stage-1/4e35c1945e3eb656548f6ff7a0d33774c1b011f9  analyze response header of this request in which you can find Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=google.
[image: check the response header content-disposition , filename]
so if filename send by server somehow then it can be possible to say to set default image name.

Answer (score -1):

I know the question is tagged HTML and JS but I needed to do this and for me it made sense to do it in PHP.  If you are able to write HTML and JS then you're likely to be able to write PHP as well so maybe this will be helpful to someone.

```
<?php 
$url = "https://yourwebsite.com/assets/image.png";
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
$myfile = fopen("images/custom_name.png", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $contents);
fclose($myfile)

?>
<a href="https://yourwebsite.com/images/custom_name.png" download>
    <button>Download image</button>
</a>
```

And then you could easily wrap this in a loop for multiple images with the loop integer becoming part of the filename.