# How to download the canvas as PNG with a custom filename?

Tags: javascript

I am using this function to download the CANVAS as a PNG image:

```
function download(){
   var canvas = document.getElementById("wordcanvas");
   var img    = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
   var url = img.replace(/^data:image\/[^;]+/, 'data:application/octet-stream');
   window.open(url);
 }
```

but the name of the downloaded file is "download".

How can I change it ( for example "myimage.png" instead of "download" ) ?

P.S. I don't want to use the download html5 attribute because it's not supported from old browsers.

Comment: @Andreas I have just changed it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change save image to file default name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37859069/how-to-change-save-image-to-file-default-name)