# Can only save canvas when code opened locally, not when viewed online

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

Trying this code (added it to the end of my canvas javascript), in order to save a png image of my canvas

```
function to_image(){
    document.getElementById("theimage").src = canvas.toDataURL();
}

function download_image(){
    var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");          
    window.location.href=image;
}

document.getElementById('bt_draw').onclick = to_image
document.getElementById('bt_download').onclick = download_image

draw()
```

So this saves a random png file to my Downloads folder. However, opening the HTML file on a browser, the save 'Download Image' button doesn't do anything

Comment: possible duplicate of [Saving the html 5 canvas image on local harddrive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063002/saving-the-html-5-canvas-image-on-local-harddrive)

Comment: @diodeus not really... they're using a different library, different code, different results, asking a different question.

Answer (score 0):

As you were, you can use `canvas.toDataURL('image/png');` to convert a canvas to a base64 data string (`data:image/png;base64,...`), then use the HTML5 `download` tag on an `a` element to provide a link to download the image. Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/AFq3Z/) (The image downloaded will be a [1x1px transparent gif](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/base64-encode-of-1x1px-transparent-gif/)).

```
<a download="filename.png" href="data:image/png;base64...">
```

It won't download specifically to the user's downloads folder (they get to choose), but they will be able to download the image as if it were a file on the server.

Comment: Can you start a chat please?

Comment: `<a id="downloadImgLink" onclick="$('#downloadImgLink').attr('href', canvas.toDataURL());" download="MyImage.png" href="#" target="_blank">Download Drawing</a>`

Comment: I tried this, the file it downloads, when opened gives: It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognize.

Comment: Try setting the `href` value before the `onclick` event.

Comment: Like this? `<a id="downloadImgLink" href="data:image/png;base64..." onclick="$('#downloadImgLink').attr('href', canvas.toDataURL());" download="MyImage.png" target="_blank">Download Drawing</a>`
Nothing is downloaded now.

Comment: Like move the code in the `onclick` event to your main script and have it fire well before the use clicks on the button.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43363/discussion-between-robotturtle-and-michael-tang)